# How might I retrieve unique records from this table?

Tags: sql, join, unique

I have two tables: CardInfo and CardItems, so each CardInfo may have multiple CardItems. I need a SQL query to fetch unique records from CardInfo  on the basis of some conditions which relates with both CardInfo and CardItems tables.

```
select c.* from CardInfo c, CardItems ci
where c.cr_no = ci.cr_no and ci.wc_id = 'test'
```

The above query return duplicate records. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove duplicate records with `DISTINCT`

```
select distinct c.* from CardInfo c, CardItems ci
where c.cr_no = ci.cr_no and ci.wc_id = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select c.* from cardinfo as c innerjoin carditems as ci
        on c.cr_no=ci.cr_no
where ci.wc_id = 'test'
```

Comment: will u please post the image of your table data. i will check and back to you asap.

Comment: only use of Distinct returns unique items, check binil's answer